# RSA encryption and decryption

Tags: php, encryption

im doing an assignment for school and we have to use rsa to crypt and sending data (for example password) to the server for user authentication i'm using php class for thet
phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation !

i can encrypt text

```
<?php
include('Math/BigInteger.php');
include('Crypt/Hash.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($rsa->createKey());

$plaintext = 'terrafrost';

$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);


echo"<form action=\"dec.php\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"ciphertext\" type=\"text\"  value=\"".$ciphertext."\"/>";

echo"<input name=\"publickey\" type=\"text\"  value=\"".$publickey."\"/>";
echo"<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" id=\"button\" value=\"Submit\" /></form>";


?>
```

but when i send the encrypted code to another page and try to decrypt it i get a errors

> Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]:
>   Type N: not enough input, need 4, have
>   3 in C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on
>   line 972
>
> Warning: extract() expects parameter 1
>   to be array, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on line
>   972
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: length in
>   C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on line
>   973
>
> Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]:
>   Type N: not enough input, need 4, have
>   0 in C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on
>   line 974
>
> Warning: extract() expects parameter 1
>   to be array, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on line
>   974
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: length in
>   C:\wamp\www\RSA\Crypt\RSA.php on line
>   975

here is my decryption page :

```
    <?php
    include('Math/BigInteger.php');
    include('Crypt/Hash.php');
    include('Crypt/RSA.php');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

    $publickey=$_POST['publickey'];
    $ciphertext = $_POST['ciphertext'];

    $rsa->loadKey($publickey);
    echo $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);

?>
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: Have you tried the library without sending with forms? If not, do that first. Perhaps check the value of the public key and ciphertext before and after sending through forms.

Comment: Try with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929780/phpseclib-decrypt-and-encrypt-data-with-only-public-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Encrypt with the public key, decrypt with the private key
2. Base64 encode the cipher before posting it, base64 decode it before decrypting it